# OData made from objects

Tags: vb.net, odata

Lets say I have a class called "Item" and "SubItems"

```
Public Class SubItem
    Private _SubItemName As String
    Public Property SubItemName() As String
        Get
            Return _SubItemName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _SubItemName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<DataServiceKey("Name")> _
Public Class Item
    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _SubItems As List(Of SubItem)
    Public Property SubItems() As List(Of SubItem)
        Get
            Return _SubItems
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of SubItem))
            _SubItems = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class
```

How would I create a service that would return a list of Items and upon looking up an individual item I would be able to see the sub items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out WCF Data Servies reflection provider, e.g.,
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/06/11/tip-56-writing-an-odata-service-using-the-reflection-provider.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728281.aspx

Hope this helps.